# Merging verticies on different objects before boolean union

Tags: vertices

I have three objects; two claws and a cylinder like object I want to join the claws to (its meant to be a crab claw). If I do a boolean union as they are now it turns out unnatural as per the image below.  [image]

So I've gone back to before the boolean union to try and merge the verticies together to get a more natural look but the points don't seem to merge together on different objects second photo.[image]  Nothing seems to merge.  When I try to move the verticies by hand they go all over the place.

Am I going about this in the wrong way?

Answer (score 1):

The 'Merge' operation requires that geometry be of the same mesh, It's obscured by the fact you have 2 objects selected, in edit mode at once.

The equivalent 'displace to center' without actual merging would be a scale by zero  <kbd>S</kbd> <kbd>0</kbd>

If you want to be able to merge verticies, you would need to join <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>J</kbd> your two objects